# frontdoor origin with private endpoint not giving the approve option

Tags: azure-appservice, azure-front-door

I create a new front door using the quick create option. I add an origin with a private endpoint, and then go to the app service to approve the private endpoint connection. This works as expected.

If I create a new endpoint and origin, in the existing front-door, I never see the private endpoint in the app service, so I can't approve. The new private endpoint never appeaers with the pending status.

What could be causing it to act differently when I use the quick create option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created front door with quick create option added origin with a private endpoint got app service to approve the private endpoint connection like below:

[image]

In App service:

[image]

> **Note** that According to this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/private-link#association-of-a-private-endpoint-with-an-azure-front-door-profile) If two or more Private Link enabled origins are created with the same set of Private Link, resource ID and group ID, then for all those origins only one private endpoint gets created, within a single Azure Front Door profile. By using this private endpoint connections to the backend can be enabled

> you have to approve the private endpoint once because only one private endpoint gets created. If you create more Private Link enabled origins using the same set of Private Link location, resource ID and group ID, you won't need to approve any more private endpoints.

Now I created new private endpoint and origin in the existing front-door I didn't receive approve it use same private endpoint.

[image]

When I created new private endpoint and origin with different Host name and origin header **`app170.azurewebsite.net`** I got pending status and approved like below

[image]

[image]